# How to fix CSS Edge Blur Effect?

Tags: html, css

I have a header where I placed a background image and blurred it. But the problem is the image edges also gets blurred which gives bad effect. How can I fix this?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nwbt2jxp/

My Code(CSS):

```
header.main::before{
    content: "";
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-image: url('https://s3.envato.com/files/225054911/Network%20590x332.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: -1;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 90vh;
    -webkit-filter: blur(4px);
    -o-filter: blur(4px);
    -moz-filter: blur(4px);
    -ms-filter: blur(4px);
    filter: blur(4px);
}

header.main{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<header class = "main">
   <p class = "text">Some text here. Loren Ipsum.</p>
</header>
```

When I do this, the edge of background image get blurred too. How to fix this so that edges don't get blurred?

Comment: Blur the image with an external editor and resave it.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `transform: scale(1.22); overflow:hidden;` to remove edge blur effect.

```css
header.main::before{
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url('https://s3.envato.com/files/225054911/Network%20590x332.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: -1;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90vh;
  -webkit-filter: blur(4px);
  -o-filter: blur(4px);
  -moz-filter: blur(4px);
  -ms-filter: blur(4px);
  filter: blur(4px);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.22);
  transform: scale(1.22);
  overflow: hidden;
}

header.main{
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header class = "main">       
       <p class = "text" style = "color: white;">Some text here. Loren Ipsum.</p>
</header>

<!-- The edge too get blurred. How to fix? -->
```

Comment: And what about the down edge? Still gets blurred.

Comment: @Fred , I have updated code. Please check. For down edge, pls  increase scale value.

Comment: Not working at all. Should i wrap the header in a div?

Comment: @Fred k you can. but here in snippet code its working.

Comment: @Fred , Be careful about that You can give `height` and `width` in `header.main:before` class.

Comment: Here's the image.

Comment: @Fred , I think you define small height not define as you mention in snippet code.

Comment: @Fred , you don't want image in full screen..?